На 4 icmp реквеста получаю 8 реплаев
Всем привет! собственно в титле указана необъяснимая мною загадка которую задали на собесе. Допустим у меня есть сеть 192.168.0.0/24; 192.168.0.1 маршрутизатор по-умолчанию; 192.168.0.2 мой хост; при попытке пингануть например 192.168.0.50 я получаю в 2 раза больше icmp ответов, в чем чисто теоретически может быть связано такое поведение? на ум приходят только зеркалирование на свиче либо включенный local-proxy-arp на gw, может кто сталкивался либо знает ответ?
